# Broken glossary/acronym links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms, links

I'm using the `glossaries`  package to set up a list of acronyms on my document, and also using the `hyperref` package. However, while my list of acronyms displays the corresponding pages for each acronym with an hyperlink, the acronym on that page links to the beginning of the document instead of the corresponding glossary entry.

Package definition on my document:

```
\usepackage{dissertation}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{%
    agrave={à},
    ccedilla={ç},
    Euro={¤}
}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{listgroup}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Acronyms}
```

As I've read that the order of the `\usepackage` commands can be relevant, could the problem be caused by that?

EDIT: Forgot the relevant `glossaries` line.

Comment: Yes, the order of loading the packages matters in some cases, especially with `hyperref` and `glossaries`, which is apparently not loaded here at all? Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Edited my question. Hard to supply a compilable example, document is very long and not very well organized. I'll try to upload it even though.

Comment: Regarding the long document problem, you can delete anything (including loaded packages), recompile and check if the problem persists. what remains at the end should be (close to) an MWE.
And while we're at it, if you suspect that the order is relevant, have you considered changing it just to try this?